# I have error when i want to use httpclient in blazor server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.(HttpClient httpClient, string requestUri)

```
public class IndexBase:ComponentBase
{
    
    public readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

    public IEnumerable<Category> categories { get; set; }
   

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        
        categories=  await httpClient.GetJsonAsync<Category[]>("api/Category");

    }
}
```

and add code in startup

```
services.AddHttpClient("ServerApi",clint =>
        {
            clint.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44363/");
        });
```

Comment: you're missing `= new HttpClient();`

Comment: when i add = new HttpClient() i have this error
InvalidOperationException: An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.(HttpClient httpClient, string requestUri)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `NullReferenceException` appears because `httpClient` is null.

You should make `httpClient` like this so that dependency injection can set it properly:

```cs
public class IndexBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    public HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }
}
```

It needs a property, not a field and requires an Inject attribute.

Comment: i edit code  like 
public class IndexBase : ComponentBase
{
    public HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }
}
but
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: you had a different error in question before, now its some invalid operation url. it states that the URL is invalid, you could try specifying that it is Absolute for base address and that it is relative for the request itself.

Comment: Nearly right, but this is Blazor, so you need to decorate the property with an `[Inject]` attribute to get it injected from the DI container.